# Animate Element in React

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have a component within a react/mobx application, which observes a certain property of a provided ui store. Whenever this property changes some elements of the component will hide / show. 
As far as I understand it, the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` is for animating components upon mount / unmount. How do I animate an element (a div to be precise) within a component, which is hidden via `display:none` but will appear upon chaning the store properties?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: none` you should set `opacity: 0` to hide and `opacity: 1` to show. Then you can animate the transition using basic CSS transitions like

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
transition: all 1s;
```

Comment: This would lead to the elements still having full height, width, thus receiving click events, influencing page flow etc.

Comment: If you use `display: none` and then `display: block` the transition will be cluttered as you cannot animate display property. To fix that you can use `height: 0` and then animate the height property when you want the div visible.

Comment: unfortunately animation to height:auto is not supported, you need to specify either fixed height or use max-height "hack": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css

Answer (score 0):

Check out css [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation) property. It will animate the element when it is added to the DOM. So, don't hide the element with `display:none`, but simply don't render it. When props changes just render it with css animation defined ;)

It is supported by all browsers, IE from v10 (which is quite enough).